# How can all functions in a workflow be run in parallel simultaneously?

Tags: powershell

When many functions are run in a parallel workflow, only 5 functions are run simultaneously.

For example, running this script:

```
function func1 { echo "I'm func1"; sleep(5); echo "func1 finished"; }
function func2 { echo "I'm func2"; sleep(5); echo "func2 finished"; }
function func3 { echo "I'm func3"; sleep(5); echo "func3 finished"; }
function func4 { echo "I'm func4"; sleep(5); echo "func4 finished"; }
function func5 { echo "I'm func5"; sleep(5); echo "func5 finished"; }
function func6 { echo "I'm func6"; sleep(5); echo "func6 finished"; }
function func7 { echo "I'm func7"; sleep(5); echo "func7 finished"; }
function func8 { echo "I'm func8"; sleep(5); echo "func8 finished"; }
function func9 { echo "I'm func9"; sleep(5); echo "func9 finished"; }
function func10 { echo "I'm func10"; sleep(5); echo "func10 finished"; }

workflow run { parallel { func1; func2; func3; func4; func5; func6; func7; func8; func9; func10; } }; run;
```

Produces this output:

```
I'm func1
I'm func2
I'm func5
I'm func4
I'm func3
func2 finished
func1 finished
func4 finished
func5 finished
func3 finished
I'm func7
I'm func8
I'm func9
I'm func6
I'm func10
func7 finished
func8 finished
func6 finished
func9 finished
func10 finished
```

How can the 5 function limit be increased?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533050/powershell-workflow-thread-limit

Comment: @DavidBrabant not ideal but it works. Thank you!